# Plot percentage of clients that earn

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage

I have a data set that shows how much someone earns. Generating syntethic data:

```
set.seed (100)
ddata <- data.frame(amount = rbeta(10000,2,20) * 1000)
ddata <- ddata %>%
  group_by(amount) %>%
  summarise(proportion = n()) %>%
  mutate(Perc = cumsum(100*proportion/sum(proportion)), 
        reverse = length(.)-Perc)
```

To see the distribution of the data, it's left skewed.

```
hist(ddata$amount)
```

I have created a percentage rank column as 'Perc', that shows me **the number of clients that earn X or less than X amount**. Below is the code for the chart:

```
ddata %>% 
ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x = amount, y = Perc, color = '#EF010C')) +
ylab("% Clients") +
xlab("Amount earned")
```

I need to create the reverse of this chart, in other words I also need to create a chart showing
me **the number of clients that earn X or more than X**. I created column 'reverse' for this purpose, the curve shape seems to be correct but the percentage showing on the y-axis is in negatives. How can I fix this? Any help will be appreciated. Finally, the curve should follow a shape similar to the histogram shown earlier.

Chart with the wrong axis:

```
ddata %>% 
ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x = amount, y = reverse, color = '#EF010C')) +
ylab("% Clients") +
xlab("Amount earned")
```

Comment: `length(.)` is giving you `2` because that code returns the number of vectors (ie columns) that exist in the data as of the `summarize` step. As @ale_ish notes, you probably meant to subtract the `Perc` from 100, instead of from 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.seed (100)
ddata <- data.frame(amount = rbeta(10000,2,20) * 1000)
ddata <- ddata %>%
  group_by(amount) %>%
  summarise(proportion = n()) %>%
  mutate(Perc = cumsum(100*proportion/sum(proportion)), 
         reverse = 100-Perc) #Changed this

ddata %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = amount, y = Perc, color = '#EF010C')) +
  ylab("% Clients") +
  xlab("Amount earned")

ddata %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = amount, y = reverse, color = '#EF010C')) +
  ylab("% Clients") +
  xlab("Amount earned")
```

Like this?

Comment: If you move color = '#EF010C' to after aes(), it gets even better

Answer (score 1):

You can get the empirical cumulative distribution of your values by using `ecdf`. The inverse is just 100% - the ecdf:

```r
set.seed (100)
ddata <- data.frame(amount = rbeta(10000,2,20) * 1000)
ddata <- ddata %>%
  mutate(Perc = ecdf(amount)(amount) * 100,
         reverse = 100 - Perc)

ddata %>% 
ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x = amount, y = Perc), color = '#EF010C') +
ylab("% Clients") +
xlab("Amount earned")
```

[image]

```r
ddata %>% 
ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x = amount, y = reverse), color = '#EF010C') +
ylab("% Clients") +
xlab("Amount earned")
```

[image]